# retriving php variable in c#

Tags: c#, php, variables

I have a PHP script which redirects the user to a file download. Upon viewing this page in a web browser I am automatically prompted for a location to save the file, with the correct filename and extension inside the `SaveFileDialog`.

I wish to download this file using an application written in C#. How can I retrieve the filename and extension of the file that is included in the response from the PHP script?

I think have to read the PHP variable, but I have not found the correct method to read it.
The PHP variables in which I am storing the filename and extension are `$file` and `$ext` respectively.

I've read several questions here, but I'm confused. Some user speak about `WebClient`, others speak about `HttpWebRequest`.

Can you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: In your PHP script, which method are you using to deliver the file to the user?

Comment: is function taked from phpbb3. that is in file.php.you can view by find my other question asked today.

Comment: Do you have a working, online example of your PHP script?

Comment: yes,it is now settig to run only via my application.

Comment: ops,iv'e preess enter key :((  the correct code is [link]http://pastebin.com/QvjZM5b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bfarley/simplewebfiledownload11162005015304am/simplewebfiledownload.aspx), where the process of downloading and saving file is described.

Here's how to get file name from the request response headers:

```
String header = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
String filename = new ContentDisposition(header).FileName;
```

And one more notice: here client is WebClient component. And here is how to use download with WebClient: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)

------The full solution ----------------------------

As it turned out, your server uses authentication. That's why in order to download file we have to pass authentication. So, **PLEASE** write full details. And here's the code:

```
 private class CWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CWebClient()
            : this(new CookieContainer())
        { }
        public CWebClient(CookieContainer c)
        {
            this.CookieContainer = c;
        }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new CWebClient();
        client.BaseAddress = @"http://forum.tractor-italia.net/";
        var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
        loginData.Add("username", "demodemo");
        loginData.Add("password", "demodemo");
        loginData.Add("login","Login");
        loginData.Add("redirect", "download/myfile.php?id=1622");
        client.UploadValues("ucp.php?mode=login", null, loginData);

        string remoteUri = "http://forum.tractor-italia.net/download/myfile.php?id=1622";
        client.OpenRead(remoteUri);
        string fileName = String.Empty;
        string contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition))
    {
        string lookFor = @"=";
        int index = contentDisposition.IndexOf(lookFor, 0);
        if (index >= 0)
            fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length+7);
    }//attachment; filename*=UTF-8''JohnDeere6800.zip

       client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);


    }
```

On my PC that works.

Comment: there is process for direct download file,in our example i know filename and extension. i nedd haow to retrive it when data is generated in a php file.

Comment: @devilkkw please see my comment on your question.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in line String header = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];

Comment: First: does your script contains content-disposition property in header?

Comment: I give up. Please ensure that you're actually creating a client, and making the download. Also **use the debugger** to check the values of the properties and variables to discover which object is null.

Comment: see the script in my commen on question.

Comment: Could you give the URL of working script? and I will write the full solution.

Comment: [link](http://forum.tractor-italia.net/download/myfile.php)  for use add at end "?id=1622"

Comment: It looks like i have no permissions to download file. My login is seeker. Could you provide username/password or tell me what does that mean? Non sei autorizzato a scaricare questo allegato.

Comment: use demodemo  for username and password

Comment: i've solved myself using HttpWebRequest requestph = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                 
requestph.Method = "HEAD";

Comment: Very well. Would you mind to paste your current source to pastebin? Just to compare.

Comment: problem don't are php,but in c#.just retrive information by using  `HttpWebRequest requestph = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                 // instruct the server to return headers only
                 requestph.Method = "HEAD";
                 // make the connection
                 responseph = requestph.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                 // get the headers
                 //headers = response.Headers;
                 lastModifyString = responseph.Headers.Get("Content-Disposition");'

Comment: Sure, problem was why that couple of lines in WebClient example wouldn't work is that you have to be logged in to perform operation.

Comment: yes,i've see :( . is possible to modify php to check if is a my program connected.i've made a simple string to check,this works but when i check, program is in crash. i have this in php: '$check = "key"; 
$prgkey = $_POST["mykey"];' i use value collection in program then use uploadValue to POST key.if key is incorrect program works correctly and send me message "403 forbidden",but when key is correct,program block and i have to stopping debug. where is my error?

Comment: What do you mean by block? I can't tell you the exact answer because I don't see your C# code. Probably the reason is incorrect headers handling. and what's wrong with C# code that I have posted?

Comment: your code is good,but i've modified check function. in php now i have [this](http://pastebin.com/P7Tm22BD) and in my program i use [program](http://pastebin.com/AKe2zbbP). Thank u so much,u are a nice helper.I've modified because i don't need user have to login via program.but i dont' want user able to download without my program ;)

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the work of PHP script in browser? I mean by passing check `valu`e and try to download file? Does that work?